# MongoDB Import Generates unexplained null values

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a large file in json format that I imported to Mongodb using Mongodb compass tool, The import is completed but when I look the data, under some fields I see null values that are not in the file I imported.

Here is the section of the document in question:
[image: Data I Want to import]

Here is how it looks in Mongodb:

[image: How it looks like in Mongodb]

it even seems to add another array under the original array with. like why 10 nulls? and why nested array ?

Thank you

Comment: FYI, When I insert 1 document instead of the whole file it works fine.

Comment: Looks like its a bug

Comment: bug filed: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-5937

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're experiencing this behavior is because the field name contains a period (`.`). I believe previously `$` and `.` weren't allowed in field names at all, but it looks like [starting with MongoDB 5.0 there is improved support for fields with `$` or `.`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restrictions-on-Field-Names).

On the same page, there is a section titled [Import and Export Concerns With Dollar Signs (`$`) and Periods (`.`)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#import-and-export-concerns-with-dollar-signs-----and-periods--.-), with the following warning:

> Starting in MongoDB 5.0, document field names can be dollar (`$`) prefixed and can contain periods (`.`). However, [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongoimport) and [`mongoexport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongoexport) may not work as expected in some situations with field names that make use of these characters.
>
> [MongoDB Extended JSON v2](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#std-label-extended-json-high-level-ref-v2) cannot differentiate between type wrappers and fields that happen to have the same name as type wrappers. Do not use Extended JSON formats in contexts where the corresponding BSON representations might include dollar (`$`) prefixed keys. The [DBRef](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#std-label-dbref-explanation) mechanism is an exception to this general rule.
>
> There are also restrictions on using [`mongoimport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongoimport) and [`mongoexport`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongoexport) with periods (`.`) in field names. Since CSV files use the period (`.`) to represent data hierarchies, a period (`.`) in a field name will be misinterpreted as a level of nesting.

The last section is most relevant to your case. Typically, MongoDB uses [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to indicate a nested field, or the [index of an array](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#arrays).

So when you import a document with a field named `MPA Content Security Program v4.10`, MongoDB is interpreting this as an array named `MPA Content Security Program v4`, with an element at the 10th index with a value of `["MS-1.0", "MS-1.1", "MS-1.2", "MS-1.3"]`.